# Server-Sent Event method not handled by Firefox

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, server-sent-events

I am building a rails application using ActionController::Live and and Custom SSE library,
My server is puma, and rails version is 4 this is my code in my controller:

```
include ActionController::Live
def index
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
ss = Reloader::SSE.new(response.stream)
100.times {
  ss.write({ :message => "just checking"}, :event => 'refresh')
  sleep 10
}

ensure
   ss.close
end
```

and this is my Library sse.rb file

```
class SSE
def initialize io
  @io = io
end

def write object, options = {}
  options.each do |k,v|
    @io.write "#{k}: #{v}\n"
  end
  @io.write "data: #{JSON.dump(object)}\n\n"
end

def close
  @io.close
end
end
```

and this is my application.js file to handle SSE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var source = new EventSource('/');
    source.addEventListener('refresh', function(e) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }, 1);
});
```

I am following the tutorial from this site http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html
Whenever I load my Firefox page, it is not handling the stream, instead it is showing the option to download the stream as text file. I don't why this is happening.

Comment: SSE is a royal pain to get working. Does your setup work with Chrome?

Comment: no it's not working in chrome as well, i just checked. The thing i noticed is EventSource method is not working from what i can see on the console.

Comment: Okay, this certainly extends the possible issues somewhat

Comment: Have you tried just sending a single message (without the sleep, etc)? We found that totally caused a problem for us

Comment: i will try it right now

Answer (score 0):

My understanding here of the SSE is at fault here, the SSE and the page/controller i am working, i took them as one, i was trying to view the controller of SSE in firefox or chrome. Very poor understanding on my part of the SSE. SSE controller and the page i want to trigger events are completely different. I got this answer at the end of this tutorial

http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html

Hope you guys got it too.